# What data structure should I use in C#? List of lists? Jagged array?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Let's say I work at the Department of Health and have compiled a log of complaints from customers who suffered food poisoning.  I also have a list of restaurants in my city which are assigned a 5 digit number.  For each complaint I know the following information:

- Restaurant's 5-digit ID
- Name/address/age of food poisoning victim
- Date of complaint

I would like to match complaints to the restaurant so that the first element in the list or array or data structure is the 5 digit ID.  The rest of the data structure for any particular restaurant will have the name/address/age of food poisoning victim, and the date of complaint.

Now keep in mind, some restaurants will get 0 complaints and others might get as many as 50.  I don't know the number in advance as I go through the log of complaints.  I basically want to assign each complaint to a data structure for the restaurant for further analysis.  This made me think I need a jagged array...but some might say I need a list of lists.

Comment: does the 5-digit ID imply any kind of sorting? If not, use a Dictionary with the ID as key.

Comment: *"Does anyone have the answer?"* There is no right or wrong answer for this one. This question is too broad and potentially opinion based, which is why you are getting down votes.

Comment: @thriqon the 5-digit ID is used so that I cannot know the restaurant's name.  it maybe a well-known 5 star restaurant or a hole-in-the-wall joint.  I might sort the 5-digit ID by ascending order in order to look up complaints for a particular restaurant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A jagged array seems to be not a great fit for this use case.  I would do something like this.  It has the benefit of having clearly typed fields for each different type of data.

```
void Main() {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = new List<Restaurant>();
}

class Restaurant {
    public int Id;
    public List<Complaint> Complaints = new List<Complaints>();
}

class Complaint {
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime ComplaintDate;
}
```

Comment: +1 Also has the benefit of being a couple minutes away from being stored in / fetched from a database with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

For a data structure in memory where every value is stored for grouping or analysis, I would suggest using a Dictionary. The key is the Restaurant id, and the value was a list of complaints. This will be good for grouping if you were setting up some presentation logic, or for getting to one of the values quickly.

```
class Complaint
{
 RestaurantId, Name, Address, etc.
}

var AllComplaints = new Dictionary<int,List<Complaint>>();
var complaint = new Complaint();
if( AllComplaints.HasKey(complaint.RestaurantId) )
{
 AllComplaints[complaint.RestaurantId].Add(complaint);
}else{
 AllComplaints[complaint.RestaurantId] = new List<Complaint>();
 AllComplaints[complaint.RestaurantId].Add(complaint);
}
```

However, if you are going to be persisting this information into a database, then there will need to a different structure *for mapping to the database*, similar to what is shown by @recursive.